# Layout half image half listview (Do I use ListActivity)?

Tags: android, listactivity

I have created a layout that is one half imageView and one half listView. I have only created listViews before that took up the entire layout. Does this mean I have to extend activity or listActivity?

Comment: u can use both list activity or activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, A `ListActivity` would be preferred here since you're still using a list. You can still make changes to your picture with a `ListActivity` as you can do the same as if it were a normal `Activity`

Comment: Please also note, that if you use ListActivity, you'll need to provide its custom layout. This layout should have ListView with id `@android:id/list` and (optionally) TextView element with id `@android:id/empty` to show message when list is empty.